# Laravel 5.7: Where can I register the allowed GET parameters and block others?

Tags: php, laravel, query-string, laravel-5.7, whitelist

I have simple Laravel application and I have custom allowed GET parameters for my app:

```
$allowedGetParameters = [
  'user',
  'event',
  'action'
]
```

How can I block all other GET parameters except the specified parameters in the array?

**For example possible URL addresses:**

```
 - https://app.com/?user=16
 - https://app.com/?event=242&user=16
 - https://app.com/?user=16&event=242&action=like
```

**URL with other GET parameters must return response 404. Here example URLs:**

```
 - https://app.com/?user=16&post=43&like=true
 - https://app.com/?guru=242&set=superguru&action=true
```

**Note:**

If the URLs contain one or more unallowed GET parameters ***with or without allowed GET parameters*** in this case, the result should also be returned 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create middleware https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware

implement `handle` method, where you are make your checks:

```
$params = array_keys($request->all());
$is_valid_params = count(array_diff($params, $allowedGetParameters)) == 0;
$is_get_request = $request->method() == 'GET';
if ($is_valid_params && $is_get_request) {
    return $next($request);
};
return abort(404);
```

Also I would move $allowedGetParameters to config folder in somefile.php, and would access like that: `count(array_diff($params, config('somefile.allowedGetParameters')) == 0;`

Don't forget to:

1) register your middleware in app\Http\Kernel.php in `protected $routeMiddleware`

2) wrap your routes in web.php with:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['name_of_your_widdleware']], function () {
```

Comment: Can be written as `if (!array_diff_key($request->all(), array_flip($allowedGetParameters)) && $request->method() === 'GET') {
    return $next($request);
}`